# Generics with Automapper - return single record

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, mapping

I have some code like this:

```
Public Function MakeDatareaderList(Of I As New)(ByVal objDR As DbDataReader) As List(Of I)
            Dim list As List(Of I)
            Mapper.CreateMap(Of DbDataReader, List(Of I))()
            list = Mapper.Map(Of SqlDataReader, List(Of I))(CType(objDR, SqlDataReader))
            Return list
        End Function
```

It works as expected i.e. a type is passed in and then a list of that type is returned.  Can I do something like this:

```
Public Function MakeDatareaderFirst(Of I As New)(ByVal objDR As DbDataReader) As I
            Mapper.CreateMap(Of IDataReader, IEnumerable(Of I))()
            I = Mapper.Map(Of IDataReader, IEnumerable(Of typeUSN))(objDR).First()
            Return I
        End Function
```

In the above code the error is: I cannot be used as an expression.  The above code returns a single object populated with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't created a variable to assign the result of the mapper function to have you?  you are trying to assign it to the type `I`

would this not work:

```
Public Function MakeDatareaderFirst(Of I As New)(ByVal objDR As DbDataReader) As I
    Dim instance as I
    Mapper.CreateMap(Of IDataReader, IEnumerable(Of I))()
    instance = Mapper.Map(Of IDataReader, IEnumerable(Of I))(objDR).First()
    Return instance
End Function
```

Comment: Yes that was it.  Please change typeUSN to I on line 4 for future users who may view this question.